# Detect Heap Overflow in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, heap-memory, exploit, heap-corruption

I actually work on a javascript project.

In this project i detected an application crash when i send too much data in an AJAX request. In a text shield, each time an users write a character or copy past something, i send the data as a PATCH request into the back-end. If i want to trigger the crash, i just send 4 or 5 time 10000 'a' characters.

How to detect if this crash was triggered by a javascript heap overflow? and how to protect this memory corruption?

Do you have an example of javascript Heap overflow Exploit and his protection?

Comment: Did the server or the client crash? From where do you want to detect the crash?

Comment: The client crash. When i monitor the Heap memory in chrome debugger the consummation was near to 25M.